# date format like 2nd day of September 2013 in javascript for selenium ide

Tags: javascript, date

I have JavaScript to return date format in dd-mmm-yyyy

```
var d=new Date();
var my_month=new Date();
var month_name=new\nArray(12);
month_name[0]="Jan";\nmonth_name[1]="Feb"; month_name[2]="Mar";\nmonth_name[3]="Apr"; month_name[4]="May";\nmonth_name[5]="Jun"; month_name[6]="Jul";\nmonth_name[7]="Aug"; month_name[8]="Sep";\nmonth_name[9]="Oct"; month_name[10]="Nov";\nmonth_name[11]="Dec";
d.getDate()+'-'+\n((month_name[my_month.getMonth()]))+'-'+d.getFullYear();
```

I am using this in selenium ide to format current date and it is working fine.

But I want to format current date as 2nd day of September 2013. How can I introduce st, nd, rd and th for different dates to get this format??

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code as follows:

```
var d=new Date();
var month_name=new Array(12);
month_name[0]="January";
month_name[1]="February";
month_name[2]="March";
month_name[3]="April";
month_name[4]="May";
month_name[5]="June";
month_name[6]="July";
month_name[7]="August";
month_name[8]="September";
month_name[9]="October";
month_name[10]="November";
month_name[11]="December";
var month_day = d.getDay() + 1;
var Nth = "th";
if(month_day === 1 || month_day === 21 || month_day === 31){
    Nth = "st";
}
else if(month_day === 2 || month_day === 22){
    Nth = "nd";
}
else if(month_day === 3 || month_day === 23){
    Nth = "rd";
}
alert(month_day+Nth+' day of '+(month_name[d.getMonth()])+' '+d.getFullYear());
```

To see the code in a JSFiddle, [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielBank/ZdSx8/).

Comment: getDay() should be getDate() and lose the +1. getDay() gives you the day of the week 0-6